# Looping using for or For_each | Terraform 0.12

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I need to create multiple subnets in GCP within a network. I am planning to use Terraform 0.12 syntax for the same as follows:

```
project_name = [ 
    "order-dev",
    "ship-dev"
]

variable "project_name" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "Name of the project"
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnetwork" {

  name          = "${var.project_name}-subnetwork"
  ip_cidr_range = var.subnet_ip_cidr_range
  region        = var.region
  network       = google_compute_network.network.self_link
}
```

Is there anyway to use *for* or *for_each* expression in this scenario, i am aware of using element and doing this. But want to try a different approach if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
variable "project_name" {
  type = set(string)
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnetwork" {
  for_each = var.project_name

  name          = "${each.key}-subnetwork"
  ip_cidr_range = var.subnet_ip_cidr_range
  region        = var.region
  network       = google_compute_network.network.self_link
}
```

Comment: i do have a follow up question, what if i want to include `subnet_ip_cidr_range' as well  in loop

Comment: @Sunil Stack Overflow doesn't support follow-up questions within the same question, so I'd suggest starting a new question for that in order that you can fully explain the question and allow folks to give full answers, rather than being constrained by the commenting system here.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `count` meta-argument

With your sample, something like this

```
project_name = [ 
    "order-dev",
    "ship-dev"
]

variable "project_name" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "Name of the project"
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnetwork" {
  count         = length(var.project_name)
  name          = "${var.project_name[count.index]}-subnetwork"
  ip_cidr_range = var.subnet_ip_cidr_range
  region        = var.region
  network       = google_compute_network.network.self_link
}
```

Another option is `for_each` with key-value pairs, but you only have access to one value and I don't think you can use a list variable like your sample.

```
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnetwork" {
  for_each = {
    order = "order-dev"
    ship = "ship-dev"
  }
  name          = "${key.value}-subnetwork"
  ip_cidr_range = var.subnet_ip_cidr_range
  region        = var.region
  network       = google_compute_network.network.self_link
}
```

Resources:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count-multiple-resource-instances-by-count
https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9
https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings

Comment: This is great info @Dude001, i used as below:

`resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnetwork2" {

  for_each = toset(var.project_name_1)
  name          = "${each.value}-subnetwork"
  ip_cidr_range = var.subnet_ip_cidr_range
  region        = var.region
  network       = google_compute_network.network.self_link
}`